# Ubercart Recurring fees

Tags: ubercart

I'm using [uc_recurring](http://drupal.org/project/uc_recurring) module in Drupal 6.
Added these options to the Recurring orders:

0 day|Every this one...

1 week|Every week

2 week|Every other week

3 week|Every third week

4 week|Every four week

Added recurring fee for fortnight from Product Features.

"add a fee for $2.00 charged first after 0 days and every 2 weeks after that unlimited times".

1) It's working in the cart page.(Recurring order options are showing up), and at the end it's not counting 2$. 2$ is not playing any role, how does it work?

2) On the whole how are recurring orders and recurring fee connected?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you added the sell price of product and after that in product feature add recurring fee ammount of 2$.